# System.NotSupportedException : 'The format of the given path is not supported.' C#

Tags: c#, path, notsupportedexception

For searching files in a directory, I am using this snippet of code :

```
string targetToCopy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["drive"] + element.Element("categorie").Value.ToString().Replace(" / ", @"\");  

DirectoryInfo directoryToCopy = new DirectoryInfo(targetToCopy);
```

I create the path with this string `targetToCopy`, I parse the string in `DirectoryInfo` for using the `directoryToCopy.GetFiles()` method.

This method searches files with path, and when I use this in my loop, I get an error:

> System.NotSupportedException : 'The format of the given path is not supported.'

I don't know what this error means, but if you know how to solve the problem.

Thank you and good luck :)

Comment: Which exact path are you using?

Comment: what is the value of `targetToCopy`

Comment: hi Corentin, Did the solution help resolve the problem, if not please comment here, so I can help further.

Comment: My exactly path is Z:/Salle de Bain/Joint/Joint.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined the problem by outputting my path to a log file, and finding it not formatting correctly. Correct for me was quite simply:

```
DirectoryInfo diTemp = new DirectoryInfo(strSomePath);
FileStream fsTemp = new FileStream(diTemp.FullName.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a space before the `/` in `Replace(" / ", @"\")`  therefore `String.Replace` transformation is not in effect

**Updated code**

`string targetToCopy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["drive"] + element.Element("categorie").Value.ToString().Replace("/ ", @"\");`